# Django custom manager with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a ManyToManyField with a through model in which there is a boolean field that I would like to filter upon.

```
from simulations.models import *
class DispatcherManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def completed(self):
        original = super(DispatcherManager,self).get_query_set()
        return original.filter(dispatchedsimulation__status=True)
    def queued(self):
        original = super(DispatcherManager,self).get_query_set()
        return original.filter(dispatchedsimulation__status=False)

class Dispatcher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    simulations = models.ManyToManyField('simulations.Simulation',
            through='DispatchedSimulation')
    objects = DispatcherManager()

class DispatchedSimulation(models.Model):

    dispatcher = models.ForeignKey('Dispatcher')
    simulation = models.ForeignKey('simulations.Simulation')
    status = models.BooleanField()
```

I thought that the `use_for_related_fields` variable would allow me to filter the m2m results as on a dispatcher d like so: `d.simulations.completed()` or `d.simulations.queued()` but these do not appear to work as I had expected.  Am I misunderstanding how the `use_for_related_fields` works, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs on [Using managers for related object access](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access):

> you can force Django to use the same class as **the default manager for your model** by setting the use_for_related_fields attribute on the manager class.

Meaning, in your case, you can force `d.simulation` to use the normal SimulationManager (and not DispatcherManager - DispatcherManager will be used for the opposite direction of the link. For example, `Simulation.objects.get(id=1).dispatcher_set.completed`).

I think the simplest way to achieve what you want is to define a `get_completed_simulations` and a `get_queued_simulations` methods in DispatcherManager. So the usage would be `d.get_completed_simulations()`.